# i have two buttons:"btn1,btn2",the btn2 will randomly change when i change backgound of btn1 alpha

Tags: android

I have two buttons:`btn1`, `btn2`. They are used with a same background image: `pic1.png`.
When I changed the background of the first button: `btn1` in `OnTouch` event, the code is as follows

```
onTouch_Action(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
        int r = (color) & 0xFF;
        int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(50, r, g, b)); //The other uses the same         background image buttons may also change
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
        int r = (color) & 0xFF;
        int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, r, g, b)); //The other uses the same         background image buttons may also change

    }
}
```

The second button: `btn2`, the background may also be changed, and changes are random.
How to avoid the second button changes?

Comment: Its happening because you are passing your entire view v in a tv and then applying setTextColor on tv

Answer (score 0):

Change code of onTouchEvent to

```
int color = button1.getCurrentTextColor();
int r = (color) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
button1.setTextColor(Color.argb(DOWN_Alpha, r, g, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Above, some people have misunderstood my question, now I post all the code

```
onTouch_Action(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
        int r = (color) & 0xFF;
        int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(50, r, g, b)); //The other uses the same         background image buttons may also change
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
        int r = (color) & 0xFF;
        int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int b = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, r, g, b)); //The other uses the same         background image buttons may also change

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But you said that you want to change the color of BUTTON