# Two buttons use the same background image

Tags: android, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i have two buttons:“btn1,btn2”,the btn2 will randomly change when i change backgound of btn1 alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507768/i-have-two-buttonsbtn1-btn2-the-btn2-will-randomly-change-when-i-change-backg)

In my app,I have two buttons (btn1 and btn2)use the same background image (pic1),When I change  the background's transparent of btn1.The background of btn2 change occasionally,and random.that's very odd.would anyone help me find the problem?thanks.

this is the code of changing background in `OnTouch`.when change one button's background to translucence,the other wil be influence .

```
TextView tv = (TextView) v;
int color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
int r = (color) & 0xFF;
int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int b = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
tv.setTextColor(Color.argb(50, r, g, b));
```

how to avoid them affect each other?

Comment: why dont u use selector for changing the background on touch

Comment: can you show the code where you set the onTouchListener of each?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you set transparency?

Maybe I unterstood the question wrong, but here goes:

The drawables for the same image resource in android share states for optimization. That means, when you change alpha for one drawable, it changes the alpha for the all drawables that share the same state (pointing to the same resource). To avoid such behaviour, you can call .mutate() method on a drawable to separate this drawables state from others.

So if are trying to do .getBackground().setAlpha(), you should do .getBackground().mutate().setAlpha(alpha) instead. (Note, that calling mutate() each time doesn't hurt the performance much (miniscule overhead), because once the drawable becomes mutable, mutate() method does nothing)